# WordPress to CRM send as XML for SOAP Endpoint API Key

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, soap

Hi I have a url for a SOAP endpoint for a remote CRM. I have a form submission which is being sent as XML. I am doing this via the 3rd Party Integration plugin, which is then converting to XML via another plugin. However within the plugin interface there is no field to add an API secure key which will approve the connection.

I need to write some code in Functions.PHP which will in terms of logic state the SOAP endpoint URL. State the Secure Key then send as XML.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This probably needs to happen when the form is submitted so maybe using an addAction based on that.

Comment: Solution is to append the API secure key to the form header. Or add a Filter to the XML Object(PHP Variable) via WordPress Filter Hooks and pass in the secure key as a string.